# How to create a dropdown that contains multiple editable paragraphs (sections) in a Word file?

Tags: drop-down-menu, paragraph

I need to create a Word template where I can choose from different paragraphs the one I need in the first section of the document. Something like a dropdown just instead of values I need paragraphs. It does not necessarily needs to be a dropdown, but any kind of functionality that will allow me to select from different pharagraphs (something like the optional sections in InfoPath).

Thanks,

Comment: I think you're referring to Word's Table of Contents, but I don't think this is a programming question...

Comment: Not sure how this can be achived but I am looking for a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use InfoPath as a solution. After testing a few atributes, I found InfoPath more suitable for my needs. So will use this app to create my templates as it allowes me to create multiple optional sections to choose from, which I could not find in MS Word.

Comment: I tried InfoPath, and it looks to be the only solution so far, but the forms require a lot more work, guess I have no choice. :)